# MGTwitter & Better Iphone Twitter API?

Tags: iphone

Basically I tried to get MGTwitter running but I had various issues. Is there a iphone twitter api or solution that is working out of the box? All I need to do is update a twitter status these frameworks like MGTwitter really looks like overkill, and complicated to setup.

Any thoughts on an easy to setup and use framework?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at: https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

"An easy way to get Twitter authenticating with OAuth on iPhone"

It actually uses MGTwitterEngine but makes things easier to drop in and use on iPhone.

Comment: Until this I found oauth & MGTwitter bewilderingly undocumented. The example app and libraries in that link let me get twitter into my app in about half a day. </endorsement>